# Code for stopping the overlapping of the Cron job

Tags: cron

I need to stop the overlapping of cron jobs for example:If a cron job is scheduled at morning 2 o clock for DB backup and other cron job is scheduled at morning 7 o clock for DB backup again.So i need to stop the 7 o clock scheduled cron job if the DB backup for 2 o clock is not completed.

Comment: why is this tagged java, c++, perl?

Comment: You need code for all 3 lanuguages? ps: let the jobs schedule it's self again?

Comment: in my php code, when the cron job runs, it check first on the database if there is a running cron job, then when there is none, it will add that there is a running cron job, so this way it will not overlap.

Comment: While the question is specific to cron, It should be noted that systemd-timer (a cron alternative) does not overlap by default: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203254/does-systemd-timer-unit-skip-the-next-run-if-the-process-hasnt-finished-yet

Answer (score 7):

This is what flock is for. From `man flock`:

```
...
The  third form is convenient inside shell scripts, and is usually used
       the following manner:

       (
         flock -n 9 || exit 1
         # ... commands executed under lock ...
       ) 9>/var/lock/mylockfile
...
```

In this case, flock will try to get a lock on fd 9 for `/var/lock/myfile`. If it can't (because the earlier job is still running), it will exit.

You need to put it in a script.

Comment: This is a great answer, it does work well. It helps to make a bash function which would be called in "commands executed under lock", to help readability !

Comment: Why exactly 9? What if this descriptor is already taken by some another task?

Answer (score 4):

The most straightforward way to do this would be to have your 2am and 7am tasks coordinate.  So for instance, the DB backup script could create a lock file when it executes, and check for the existence of this file when it starts up.  If the file exists it could simply exit without doing any work (or sleep for a bit, or whatever you decide).

Doing this in a completely task-agnostic way might be possible, but it's going to be trickier and unnecessary in this particular case.

Comment: A lock file would have to be managed (if backup script crashes and lock file not cleaned up), or perhaps ignored if older than 24 hrs.  Better to ask the database if it is being backed up (if that is possible in this case).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are on a Unix system: The easiest way to do this is
create a file and write the cron job's PID to it. If the file can't be
created using `open(2)` with `O_CREAT|O_EXCL` flags, it already
exists, thus the previous job is still running or has crashed without
cleaning up. The PID can be used to determine whether the job is still
running.

In your case, the safest approach is probably for the cron job to die
if the PID file is found on startup.

Since you put the `perl` tag to the question, I suggest to have a look
at the `File::Pid` and `Proc::PID::File` modules.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

```
$ crontab -l
* * * * * cd /patch/to/script; . /patch/to/.profile; overlap.pl process.sh -t Device || process.sh -t Device
$
$
$ cat overlap.pl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $cmd = join(' ',@ARGV);
my @result = `pgrep -f \"$cmd\"`;
scalar @result > 2 ? exit 0 : exit 1;
```

EXPLANATION:

- this job runs script every minute to check if it works (* * * * *)
- cron job is complex, fisrt change directory, load profile so I need to launch script directly from this job not from script that is checking if overlapped
- and then check if this particular process with the same parameters is already running (overlap.pl with exact command that I want to check)
- if "no", return 0, if "yes", return >0
- then there is logical "or" checking result and launch desired script or not

Pay attention to the array length in overlap.pl, you can check it by yourself by doing `ps -elf | grep \"$cmd\" >> /tmp/croncheck`;

Answer (score 1):

You just need something that you can check to see if the first task has finished running, and this check should be done right before the job runs again.

I'd implement this with a database (if available) or a registery key or even a text file. So your task would look like this:

```
  read job_flag
  if job_flag == 0
    step job_flag = 1
    run job
    step job_flag = 0
  else
    stop job 
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do this in a single cron job?

```
/path/to/job1 && /path/to/job2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that just using cron. You are going to have to add some logic to your script or code to check if the other one is running or not. A total hack would be to have your script check for the exists of a particular file. If it does not exist then you should create this file, perform the backup, then remove it. If the file does exist, do nothing.

That is a hack and only really works because your jobs are spaced so far apart.