# What happen if a cron schedule is 1 min and the cron runtime is 10 min?

Tags: cron

If the cron schedule is every 1 minutes, but the length of cron time is 10 min, what will happen?

```
cron:
- description: test for cron length of 10 min
  url: /test
  schedule: every 1 minutes
```

1st test is called at 00:00:00 and it will finish at 00:10:00

2nd test is called at 00:01:00 and it will finish at 00:11:00

....

Is that what will happen? Or is the second test called only after first test job is done?

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139842/code-for-stopping-the-overlapping-of-the-cron-job), they overlap - and it makes sense.

Comment: If they would interfere with each other, then upon start-up, the cron task should determine if another instance is running, and exit immediately if it is. You can do this with `ps` or with a file flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's what will happen, your cron will run the process every minute regardless of the execution time of that process. If you want to avoid concurrency use a semaphore system in your process (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29). A simple implementation would consist of the process checking for a semaphore file, checking the last modification time of that file or checking if the PID contained in that file is still running, thus deciding if your process should run or simply exit. A better implementation (if you don't care about being os-independent) would be using [flock(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/flock) to obtain a lock on a file and check that lock every time the script is executed:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # Exit on unchecked errors (can't acquire exclusive lock)
    set -e

    (
    # Wait for lock on /var/lock/.script.xlock (file descriptor 200)
    flock -x 200

    # Your code

    ) 200>/var/lock/.script.xlock #Associate file descriptor 200 with file
```